# How to create multiple table synonyms in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle

I have multiple table.

I tried to this query:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM CHKWEBUSER FOR NEST.CHKWEBUSER;
```

But I have multiple table like 5000. SO how can I create synonym in one query?

Comment: Not sure if I follow right... Do you want to create synonyms for each table in specific schema or is it something else?

Comment: I want create synonyms for all table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement will *generate* the necessary statements.

You need to spool/export the output of that statement into a SQL script and then run that script.

How you do that depends totally on which SQL client you are using. With SQL*Plus you would e.g. use the `spool` command.

```
select 'create public synonym '||table_name||' for '||owner||'.'||table_name||';'
from all_tables
where owner = 'NEST';
```

Comment: @Black: please read my answer again. The `select` will ***generate*** the necessary statements. Save the output into a file and run that file.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply create synonyms for all tables with a single command. What you need to do is to create / generate a script that will do that for you.

Here, you have a simple script that will generate a list of `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM...` commands which you can later run.

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR cTables IS
    SELECT * 
      FROM ALL_TABLES TAB
    WHERE TAB.OWNER = 'NEST'; /* Tune the where clause to your needs */

  sSql VARCHAR2(20000);

BEGIN

  FOR rTable in cTables LOOP

    sSql := 'CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM ' || rTable.TABLE_NAME || ' FOR NEST.' || rTable.TABLE_NAME || ';';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sSql);

  END LOOP;

END;
```

This script will print out commands like:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM MY_TABLE FOR NEST.MY_TABLE
```

Additionally, instead of using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` you can go with directly calling:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sSql;
```

instead. This will automagically create the synonyms for you.